# Changing from default browser to Chrome automatically when specific desktop icon is selected

Tags: browser

I'm trying to set my senior citizen mother (aka luddite!) up with Google Hangouts so she will be able to video conference with me when I'm in Panama for an extended time.  She prefers Firefox, but Hangouts only works in Chrome.  Can I force the Hangouts desktop icon to open in Chrome, even though her default browser is Firefox, and we don't want that to change for other applications?

Comment: Are you Kevin or Jane? We are confused.

Comment: This is Kevin, just trying to set my mom up.

Answer (score 3):

1. Make a copy of the current Google Chrome icon

This icon could be on your desktop already, or in your start menu. Put the icon on your desktop if that is where you want it.

1. Right click on the icon and go to Properties
2. On the General tab, change the name to "Hangouts"
3. On the Shortcut tab, edit the Target box to include "hangouts.google.com"
   [image]
4. Press OK and your Hangouts in Chrome icon is now ready to use.

Comment: Except that with Firefox as the default browser, I'm not given the "shortcut" option. Only General, Web Document, Security, Details, and Previous Versions tabs are available

Comment: you need to edit a copy of the icon that would open chrome